# Why does an error occur when running the program?

Tags: c, pointers

I have an error and I can't find a method to solve it.I get this error

> Exception thrown at 0x504A3E6C (ucrtbased.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0047617A. On line 11.

```
#include "Entities.h"
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

Expense* createExp(int nr_ap, float price, char* type) {
    Expense *e = malloc(sizeof(Expense));
    e->nr_ap = nr_ap;
    e->price = price;
    e->type = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(type) + 1);  #Here is the problem.
    strcpy(e->type, type);
    return e;
}

void destroy(Expense *e) {
    free(e->type);
    free(e);

}

int getAp(Expense *e) {
    return e->nr_ap;
}

float getPrice(Expense *e) {
    return e->price;
}

char* getType(Expense *e) {
    return e->type;
}

/*
Create a copy
*/

Expense *copyExp(Expense *e) {
    return createExp(e->nr_ap, e->price, e->type);
}

void testCreateExp() {
    Expense *e = createExp(10, 120, 'Gaz');
    assert(getAp(e) == 10);
    assert(getPrice(e) == 12);
    assert(getType(e) == "Gaz");
    destroy(e);

}

int main() {
    testCreateExp();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean: `Expense *e = createExp(10, 120, "Gaz");`?

Comment: ^ Your compiler should give an error about that, if you invoke in standard-conforming mode

Comment: Additionally, this assertion `assert(getType(e) == "Gaz")` is not doing what you think it is doing. It will always fail.

Comment: The == compares the two char pointer variables, not the strings themselves, and will only return true if the pointers are both the sameUse `strcmp` instead, and check if its return value is 0 (which means both strings are the same).

Answer (score 6):

`Expense *e = createExp(10, 120, 'Gaz');` Makes no sense. single quote are used for single characters, not C strings.

e.g. `char initial = 'G'; char* name = "Gaz";`

Try `Expense *e = createExp(10, 120, "Gaz");`. Most compilers should give you a warning that using a single quote is not right in this context.

Also suspect your asserts are not "as expected" `assert(getType(e) == "Gaz");` - shouldn't that be a `strcmp()` ?